Unable to get Lambda@Edge logs in CloudWatch
The infrastructure looks like this:

Route 53 domain to CloudFront distribution
Behind CloudFront is S3 bucket with content
There is Lambda@Edge for authorization purposes
Lambda@Edge function is triggered on viewer request.

I'm unable to find the logs of Lambda.
If I click on Test button on Lambda Console page logs are in N.Virginia region, so I guess permissions aren't the issue. I said * resources for logs:CreateLogGroup, logs:CreateLogStream, logs:PutLogEvents actions inside IAM policy of Lambda execution role. Since authorization is triggered I suppose that Lambda is also properly triggered.
I looked inside every available region and there were no logs whatsoever.

The logs for Lambda@Edge are available in the edge region corresponding to the IP address from which the request was made.
If you have selected "Use all edge locations (best performance)" in your Cloudfront distribution, then your logs will be splitted between all the regions.
For example, a request coming from a South America country will most likely be visible in the sa-east-1 region (São Paulo).
If you need to debug, then use the AWS Global Infrastructure map to figure out from which region your request is most likely to be coming from, and you should be able to find the Log Group in CloudWatch, by switching to this region using the top right selector in your console.
If you need centralized logging, you would have to ingest the logs into a centralized system, to be able to perform queries at a consolidated level. Here is one solution suggested by Amazon.
If not already done, add AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole to your lambda permissions.
